# Pyglet: scene manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, library, pyglet

This is my brief summary of Pyglet: it's a powerful, efficient, high-tech cage. But once you're in there, once you call `pyglet.app.run()`, it's all over - you can't go back. Thus, there is this huge initialization process that you must split up into as many separate pieces as you can or you'll get lost.

I tried to split it into scenes by writing a scene manager. It works, but looks horrible and I'm worried about its efficiency.

```
""" Pyglet scene manager. """

import pyglet

class Scene_Manager(object):
    """ Runs and switches between different scenes. """

    def on_step(self, dt):
        """ Logic function executed every frame. """

        if not self.running:
            self.window.close()
            pyglet.app.exit()
        else:
            self.scenes[self.current].on_step(self, dt)

    def __init__(self, start, scenes, x = 640, y = 360, title = "Untitled", fps = 30):
        """ Initialize and run. """

        self.running = True
        self.current = start
        self.scenes = scenes
        self.window = pyglet.window.Window(x, y, title)
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval( self.on_step, 1.0 / fps)

        @self.window.event
        def on_activate():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_activate(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_close():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_close(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_context_lost():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_context_lost(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_context_state_lost():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_context_state_lost(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_deactivate():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_deactivate(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_draw():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_draw(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_expose():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_expose(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_hide():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_hide(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers)

        @self.window.event
        def on_key_release(symbol, modifiers):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_enter(x, y):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_enter(self, x, y)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_leave(x, y):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_leave(self, x, y)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_motion(x, y, dx, dy):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_release(x, y, button, modifiers):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, modifiers)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_scroll(x, y, scroll_x, scroll_y):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_scroll(self, x, y, scroll_x, scroll_y)

        @self.window.event
        def on_move(x, y):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_move(self, x, y)

        @self.window.event
        def on_resize(width, height):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_resize(self, width, height)

        @self.window.event
        def on_show():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_show(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_text(text):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_text(self, text)

        @self.window.event
        def on_text_motion(motion):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_text_motion(self, motion)

        @self.window.event
        def on_text_motion_select(motion):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_text_motion_select(self, motion)

        pyglet.app.run()

class Scene(object):
    """ Scene template. """

    def on_step(self, app, dt):
        pass
    def on_activate(self, app):
        pass         
    def on_close(self, app):
        pass         
    def on_context_lost(self, app):
        pass         
    def on_context_state_lost(self, app):
        pass         
    def on_deactivate(self, app):
        pass         
    def on_draw(self, app):
        pass         
    def on_expose(self, app):
        pass         
    def on_hide(self, app):
        pass         
    def on_key_press(self, app, symbol, modifiers):
        pass         
    def on_key_release(self, app, symbol, modifiers):
        pass         
    def on_mouse_drag(self, app, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
        pass         
    def on_mouse_enter(self, app, x, y):
        pass         
    def on_mouse_leave(self, app, x, y):
        pass         
    def on_mouse_motion(self, app, x, y, dx, dy):
        pass         
    def on_mouse_press(self, app, x, y, button, modifiers):
        pass         
    def on_mouse_release(self, app, x, y, button, modifiers):
        pass         
    def on_mouse_scroll(self, app, x, y, scroll_x, scroll_y):
        pass         
    def on_move(self, app, x, y):
        pass         
    def on_resize(self, app, width, height):
        pass         
    def on_show(self, app):
        pass         
    def on_text(self, app, text):
        pass         
    def on_text_motion(self, app, motion):
        pass        
    def on_text_motion_select(self, app, motion):
        pass
```

You use it like this:

```
import pyglet
import helper

class Menu_Scene(helper.Scene):
    """ Menu scene in progress. """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bg = pyglet.image.load("menu_bg.jpg")
        self.snake = pyglet.sprite.Sprite ( pyglet.image.load("snake.png") )
        self.snake.position = 320, 0

    def on_draw(self, manager):
        super().on_draw(manager)
        manager.window.clear()
        self.bg.blit(0, 0)
        self.snake.draw()

helper.Scene_Manager("menu", {"menu" : Menu_Scene() } )
```

Before I'm going even further, splitting scenes into layers like this;

```
def on_activate(self, app):
    for layer in self.layers:
        layer.on_activate(app)
```

Please, tell me if I'm doing something really wrong. I've never written 200 lines of code so easily and quickly before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Changes

It looks good, but have you tested the fps?

The `on_draw` method of `Scene_Manager` is not limited by the `fps` parameter, only the `on_step` is.

At `Scene_Manager`, at the end of `__init__`method, for our testing, add:

```
self.fps_display = pyglet.window.FPSDisplay(self.window)  # for our test
```

And then edit the `on_draw` window event to show it:

```
@self.window.event
def on_draw():
    self.scenes[self.current].on_draw(self)
    self.fps_display.draw()  # for our test
```

If you test it now, the fps value goes wild, up to the hundreds.

Pyglet has a [built-in function to limit fps](http://pyglet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pyglet/pyglet.clock.html#limiting-frame-rate). To use it, in your `Scene_Manager`'s `__init__`, add:

```
pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(fps)
```

Note that, despite the `pyglet.clock` also having a function to show fps(`clock.ClockDisplay()`), it doesn't work, and we should actually use the `window.FPSDisplay` as we did.

Also, your [class names don't follow pep8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names). Unless you have a specific reason not to use it, they should be: `SceneManager` instead of `Scene_Manager`; `MenuScene` instead of `Menu_Scene`.

As a last suggestion, as we've already prepared the code to show the `fps_display` for our testing, it should be a good idea to take one more argument on `SceneManager.__init__`, such as `show_fps = False` to allow anyone to easily use it in case of need.

## Testable, updated code

You code relies on some images that we don't have access to.
The code below reflects the changes discussed above, adds a few minor changes on docstrings to follow [pep257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), and can be tested, which usually raises more attention/answers to a question (the sprite and bg lines that relied on images not provided were commented):

```
"""Pyglet scene manager."""

import pyglet


class SceneManager(object):
    """Runs and switches between different scenes."""

    def on_step(self, dt):
        """Logic function executed every frame."""
        if not self.running:
            self.window.close()
            pyglet.app.exit()
        else:
            self.scenes[self.current].on_step(self, dt)

    def __init__(self, start, scenes, x=640, y=360, title="Untitled",
                 fps=30, show_fps=False):
        """Initialize and run."""
        self.running = True
        self.current = start
        self.scenes = scenes
        self.window = pyglet.window.Window(x, y, title)
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.on_step, 1.0 / fps)

        self.show_fps = show_fps            
        pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(fps)
        self.fps_display = pyglet.window.FPSDisplay(self.window)

        @self.window.event
        def on_activate():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_activate(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_close():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_close(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_context_lost():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_context_lost(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_context_state_lost():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_context_state_lost(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_deactivate():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_deactivate(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_draw():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_draw(self)
            if self.show_fps:
                self.fps_display.draw()

        @self.window.event
        def on_expose():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_expose(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_hide():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_hide(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers)

        @self.window.event
        def on_key_release(symbol, modifiers):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_drag(
                self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_enter(x, y):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_enter(self, x, y)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_leave(x, y):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_leave(self, x, y)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_motion(x, y, dx, dy):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_press(
                self, x, y, button, modifiers)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_release(x, y, button, modifiers):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_release(
                self, x, y, button, modifiers)

        @self.window.event
        def on_mouse_scroll(x, y, scroll_x, scroll_y):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_mouse_scroll(
                self, x, y, scroll_x, scroll_y)

        @self.window.event
        def on_move(x, y):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_move(self, x, y)

        @self.window.event
        def on_resize(width, height):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_resize(self, width, height)

        @self.window.event
        def on_show():
            self.scenes[self.current].on_show(self)

        @self.window.event
        def on_text(text):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_text(self, text)

        @self.window.event
        def on_text_motion(motion):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_text_motion(self, motion)

        @self.window.event
        def on_text_motion_select(motion):
            self.scenes[self.current].on_text_motion_select(self, motion)

        pyglet.app.run()


class Scene(object):
    """Scene template."""

    def on_step(self, app, dt):
        pass

    def on_activate(self, app):
        pass

    def on_close(self, app):
        pass

    def on_context_lost(self, app):
        pass

    def on_context_state_lost(self, app):
        pass

    def on_deactivate(self, app):
        pass

    def on_draw(self, app):
        pass

    def on_expose(self, app):
        pass

    def on_hide(self, app):
        pass

    def on_key_press(self, app, symbol, modifiers):
        pass

    def on_key_release(self, app, symbol, modifiers):
        pass

    def on_mouse_drag(self, app, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
        pass

    def on_mouse_enter(self, app, x, y):
        pass

    def on_mouse_leave(self, app, x, y):
        pass

    def on_mouse_motion(self, app, x, y, dx, dy):
        pass

    def on_mouse_press(self, app, x, y, button, modifiers):
        pass

    def on_mouse_release(self, app, x, y, button, modifiers):
        pass

    def on_mouse_scroll(self, app, x, y, scroll_x, scroll_y):
        pass

    def on_move(self, app, x, y):
        pass

    def on_resize(self, app, width, height):
        pass

    def on_show(self, app):
        pass

    def on_text(self, app, text):
        pass

    def on_text_motion(self, app, motion):
        pass

    def on_text_motion_select(self, app, motion):
        pass


class MenuScene(Scene):
    """Menu scene in progress."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Commenting the lines that depend on images.
        # We don't have access to them.

        # self.bg = pyglet.image.load("menu_bg.jpg")
        # self.snake = pyglet.sprite.Sprite ( pyglet.image.load("snake.png") )
        # self.snake.position = 320, 0

    def on_draw(self, manager):
        super().on_draw(manager)
        manager.window.clear()
        # self.bg.blit(0, 0)
        # self.snake.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SceneManager("menu", {"menu": MenuScene()}, show_fps=True)
```